# Regex - Find first whitespace after specific character

Tags: regex, whitespace

What is the regex expression to select only part of the string from a specific character to the first whitespace (space) i.e.:

in TEXT=331-6"-PR-003-BQ163*$WR01-6"-200-300-CL,STD* SAV=0.000000 SAB=0.000000

I would like to select only the part which is italicized (between *).

BR

Comment: The specific character is `$` or `*`?

Comment: From `*` included to the first space excluded : `\*[^ ]*`. Looks like you'd better use "from one `*` to the next" though : `\*[^*]*\*`

Comment: I think he included `*` character to highlight what string he meant, and the starting character actually is `$`.

Answer (score 1):

`\*[^ ]*`

Explanation:

- `\*` asterisk character, which is our specific character (it is special symbol, so `\` is needed)
- `[^ ]*` random number of characters different than space
- space

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `$` as the starting specific character this:

```
(\$[^ ]*)\s
```

Test and explanation: https://regex101.com/r/AcSKA5/1